# Best way to deploy a Click Once application on a network

Tags: deployment, installation, clickonce, outlook-addin

I am trying to install an Outlook 365 Add In that I have developed. I have published the application as a click once which can be installed by running the setup file.

I need the application to be installed on all company computers, so the best place to host the application would be the company network.

How can I deploy my application to all users and allow the application to automatically update every time there is a new version published?

I greatly appreciate any help with this issue. This is the first large application deployment that I have undertaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't advise on the specific mechanism for deploying an "installed" version of your solution - I imagine you can accomplish that with most application deployment systems.  Otherwise users will have to run the setup.exe from your network deployment.  When you do have an update you simply copy the new files to a new versioned folder and existing installations will detect the change of version number in the deployed manifest and auto-update.  See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx

Comment: You're welcome Ron. Please upvote my answer if it helped!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote this as I do not have enough reputation yet. I will mark as answer as it has been helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed anyway